# UICollectionViewController Thumbnail Image view full screen and Scroll Gestures

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a `UICollectionViewController` that currently populates a range of images as thumbnails and a title underneath each one. What I would like to do is to use the Tap Gesture Recognizer and the Swipe Gesture Recognizer to allow the user to tap on any of the thumbnails and view a fullscreen version of the image. I also want them to then be able to swipe through the fullscreen images.

As I am new to iOS development I am not too sure how best to go about this and would really appreciate some advice/help/links etc.

When I drag a Tap Gesture Recognizer onto the `UIImageView`, within my custom Cell, that is on my `UICollectionViewController` I get the following error:

> Illegal Configuration: Gesture recognizes cannot be used on prototype objects.

Would really appreciate some help please.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to add any gesture recognisers, use the UICollectionView's built in methods.

For example, when the user taps a cell (one of your thumbnails), as long as you implement the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout (assuming you use a Flow Layout) this method will be called;

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// present a new view controller here that shows a hi res version of the image
}
```

If you want to be able to swipe through the images your best option is to open a UIPageViewController from the above method with an array of view controllers or views.